# failed to inject module factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got an error of `[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:(…)`

I have app.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute','authService']){

});
```

and a file call auth.js and it has

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('authService', function($http) {

  });
```

And I did include them in index.html

```
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/services/auth.js"></script>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject [factory to a module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di),

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']){

});
```

Your controller can inject the Factory as below,

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,authService) {
}
```

You are already adding to the module with this code, so it is not necessary to inject it again

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('authService', function($http) {

  });
```

If you want to have the factory in a different module, then use it in another module as below.

```
angular.module('MyApp2')
  .factory('authService', function($http) {

  });
```

then you can use in first app as below,

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute','MyApp2']){

});
```

Comment: @JennyMok what do you mean?

Comment: @JennyMok You can't inject service instance into `config` block.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/sahat/megaboilerplate/blob/master/examples/express-handlebars-foundation-css-angularjs-gulp-mongodb-facebook-google/public/js/app.js

Comment: @JennyMok dude! there is no place shows injecting to module